# ERROR: Access denied for user 'postgres'@'localhost' (Command Line)

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am trying to create db with sequelize cli but getting this error.

```
ERROR: Access denied for user 'postgres'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Here is my config.json file

```
    {
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "database_development",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
  }
}
```

I can login with same user on phppgAdmin which i am currently using in config.json but its throwing the error. This is default user with all permissions and i had already created a db with ui.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't PhpPgAdmin for postgresql ? You seem to try to connect to a mysql database

Comment: @Zyigh This config is created by sequelize cli on initialization.

Comment: @Zyigh phpMyAdmin works with mysql also

Comment: @ManishSaraan - you set password to 'postgres' user is it correct one?  is it suppose to be null like 'root' user?

Comment: @A.Todkar yes these are correct credentials. I can login with same on phppgAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so after messing around with config.json i figured out the solution. If you run the commands from sequalize cli documentation 
[sequalize cli doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#the-cli) then it will create the same config.json as in question. I have only modified the username and password.

The default dialect is **mysql** so you need to change it with **postgres** and it will work.